# How can I format list elements from this array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, format

I'd like to note that this is part of a much bigger script, but I've isolated the necessary components for simplicity's sake.

I'm writing a script to store student names & their associated grades (among other things) using `class Student`.  User will be asked for student name, then the number of grades they want to add.  They are then asked to input the grades (however many times they specified in 'number of grades').

After inputs are finished, the data is stored in an array like so:

```
[{'grades': [99, 88, 77], 'name': 'John Doe'}]
```

The new student data is then printed in the following format:

```
STUDENT NAME:  John Doe
GRADES:  [99, 88, 77]
```

How can I format and print the `GRADES:  [99, 88, 77]` without the brackets?  Code below.

```
students_all = []


class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, grades):
        self._name = name
        self._grades = grades

    def __str__(self):
        return "STUDENT NAME:  {}\nGRADES:  {}".format(self._name, self._grades)
                                                                ###FORMAT HERE^?###

def add_student():
    new_student = {}
    new_student["grades"] = []

    new_student["name"] = input("\nEnter student name:  ")
    while True:
        try:
            num_grades = int(input("Number of Grades:    "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter a valid number!")

    print()
    while True:
        try:
            for i in range(0, num_grades):
                grades = int(input("Enter Grade: "))
                new_student["grades"].append(grades)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter a valid number!")

    students_all.append(new_student)
    return new_student

newstudent = Student(**add_student())
print(newstudent)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use str.join():

```py
"STUDENT NAME:  {}\nGRADES:  {}".format(self._name, ", ".join(map(str, self._grades)))
```

This code also converts integers to strings.

Comment: Thanks heaps man.  Was getting errors with something similar, but I wasn't including 'map'.  Thanks a tonne!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `str.join(iterable)` function to create a string from an iterable.

For you code it would be something like this:

```py
def __str__(self):
        return "STUDENT NAME:  {}\nGRADES:  {}".format(self._name, ', '.join(self._grades))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code:

```
def __str__(self):
            return "STUDENT NAME:  {}\nGRADES:  {}".format(self._name, ', '.join(str(grade) for grade in self._grades))
```